# WPF DependencyProperty Inheritance - regular DP vs Attached

Tags: c#, wpf

1) For "Font", dependency property inheritance would just work out-of-the-box. https://wpf.2000things.com/2014/03/31/1040-an-example-of-dependency-property-inheritance/

You can change "Font" on Main Window, it'd propagate down the user controls (**no changes** in any child user controls for this to work).

2) If you want to make DP inheritance works for your own DPs, your DPs must be **"Attached Properties"** and you do so by
a. **FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits**
b. From class subscribing to property inheritance: MyClass.InheritedValueProperty.**AddOwner**

http://devcomponents.com/blog/?p=495

How come "out-of-the-box" DPs gets DP inheritance out of box, whereas if you want your own DP inheritance to work, there're so many constraints (Your DP must be "Attached Properties", things to implement (So much boilerplate code in any class subscribing to it)?

For "out-of-the-box" WPF implementation, I assume those boilerplate code in framework base class **"DependencyObject"**? Further, "Font" is a DP defined in framework base class **"Control"** (Even MainWindow is a Control) -
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.control?view=netframework-4.7.2
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window?view=netframework-4.7.2

WPF DepdendencyObject must have implemented out-of-box DP inheritance for out-of-box DPs such as Font?

Comment: This topic is explained in detail in [Property Value Inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/property-value-inheritance). Pay special attention to the [Making a Custom Property Inheritable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/property-value-inheritance#making-a-custom-property-inheritable) section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is exactly how it is implemented for the out-of-the-box WPF properties such as FontFamily. The FontFamily is declared as an attached property on the [TextElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/xaml-host-controls) class...

```
public abstract class TextElement : FrameworkContentElement, IAddChild
{

    …

    /// <summary>
    /// DependencyProperty for <see cref="FontFamily" /> property.
    /// </summary>
    [CommonDependencyProperty]
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontFamilyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "FontFamily",
            typeof(FontFamily),
            typeof(TextElement),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                SystemFonts.MessageFontFamily,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure |                 
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | 
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits),
                new ValidateValueCallback(IsValidFontFamily));
```

...and then in the [Control](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Control.cs,6750b721a2294fc5) class it is added as an owner...

```
public class Control : FrameworkElement
{
    …

    /// <summary>
    ///     The DependencyProperty for the FontFamily property.
    ///     Flags:              Can be used in style rules
    ///     Default Value:      System Dialog Font
    /// </summary>
    [CommonDependencyProperty]
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontFamilyProperty =
            TextElement.FontFamilyProperty.AddOwner(
                    typeof(Control),
                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(SystemFonts.MessageFontFamily,
                        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));
```

You have to do exactly the same as the WPF programmers did.